# Operation APPEND failed with HTTP500?

Tags: azure, kafka

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.kafkaToflink;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.RichSinkFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;

import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLException;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLFileOutputStream;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.IfExists;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.oauth2.AccessTokenProvider;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider;

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.testing.Str;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.72:9092");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");
        DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<String>("tenant", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties), "Kafka_Source");

        stream.addSink(new ADLSink()).name("Custom_Sink").setParallelism(128);
        env.execute("App");
    }
}

class ADLSink<String> extends RichSinkFunction<String> {

    private java.lang.String clientId = "***********";
    private java.lang.String authTokenEndpoint = "***************";
    private java.lang.String clientKey = "*****************";
    private java.lang.String accountFQDN = "****************";
    private java.lang.String filename = "/Bitfinex/ETHBTC/ORDERBOOK/ORDERBOOK.json";

    @Override
    public void invoke(String value) {

        AccessTokenProvider provider = new ClientCredsTokenProvider(authTokenEndpoint, clientId, clientKey);
        ADLStoreClient client = ADLStoreClient.createClient(accountFQDN, provider);
        try {
            client.setPermission(filename, "744");
            ADLFileOutputStream stream = client.getAppendStream(filename);

            System.out.println(value);
            stream.write(value.toString().getBytes());

            stream.close();

        } catch (ADLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.requestId);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }

    }

}
```

I am continuously trying to append a file which is in Azure data lake Store using while loop .But sometimes it gives this , Operation APPEND failed with HTTP500, error in starting or sometimes after 10 min. I am using java